# C# Windows Forms - how to scale application without restart?

Tags: c#, winforms, dpi

I have Windows Forms app and it is scaled correctly for different DPI.
But it only works if I stop the app, change Windows scaling setting, then restart the app. If I change scale setting while the app is running - then it remains with old scaling.
How to make my app to handle Windows scaling change like the Explorer does?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.systemevents.displaysettingschanged?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0

Comment: Thanks. Now I can handle system event. But how can I force my app to rescale itself as if it was started?

Comment: Did you finally got it work? i am trying to do the same.